# Return value from controller using $.param in MVC

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net MVC, in the application I update an image using the following:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult OutputHandler(int slide = 0)
        {
            FileContentResult data;
            im = object(slide) ......
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                objImage1.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                data = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
            }
            objImage1.Dispose();
            return data;
        }
```

In the view I use,

```
imge.src = '/Home/Animate?' + $.param({
  ....
 slide: parseInt(intervalCounter),
 mprType: 0,
 udm: ++udm
  });
```

It works well, however I need to get back the value of slide from the controller to update a variable in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201767/Load-Base64-Images-using-jQuery-and-MVC.

Changed the controller to:

```
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                    objImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                    var image = Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
                    objImage.Dispose();
                    return Json(new { success = true, base64imgage = image, slide = slide}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In the view:

```
                                        $.ajax({
                                        url: '/Home/test',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data: {
                                               .....
                                        },
                                        success: function(data) {
                                            if (data.udm) {
                                         image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ data.base64imgage + udm;
                                            }
                                        },
```

Hope this helps someone having the same challenge.

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag is very helpful in these situations.  This dynamic variable can be used to store data from the controller and then be used in the view.

In the controller you can set

```
ViewBag.Slide = slide
```

and in the view you can do what you need with this data

```
@ViewBag.Slide
```

Comment: Thank you, would the ViewBag be updated without refreshing the page?

Comment: No, it would not.  I see now that you are trying to use AJAX to call the controller.  I don't know why I missed that.

Comment: I am not as familiar with using MemoryStream, and I don't quite know how the slide value is changing in your function.  But would it be possible to create a second function that does the same process and then returns your slide value instead?  Then you could use two AJAX calls to get both pieces of invormation. Also, the new method may not need to do the computationally intensive object rendering.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I do use Ajax but it sends two request, I thought by using param I could save one request, I could be wrong.

Comment: When I'm returning multiple pieces of data using a single controller, I usually create a custom model (a separate C# or VB class) for the data I want to return with each type of data as a property.  Then I return a JsonResult of this behavior.  So I might create a OutputHandlerData class with Data and Slide as the properties.  Then I could return Json(outputHandlerData).  Do you think this might work with the FileContentResult?